# What's Libratus made of?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence, games

I'm trying to understand how Libratus is working.

I found that there were 3 main parts, one using counterfactual regret minimization to learn to play from scratch. an end-game solver as well as retraining each nights so it can adapts to pre-flop bets it has not trained on before.

I'm wondering if there's any technical details on these solutions because I can't figure out why it's necessary for Libratus to retrain on pre-flop bets.

I'm also wondering why these 3 distinct parts are not merged into one. The end-game solver seems to work a bit like AlphaGo exploration of the game tree, so why is there a need to re-train for specific pre-flop bets. Could Libratus not generalize well enough ? I've heard that it had pre-defined strategies (like for 2,5BB and 3BB bets but for 2,75 it would just round to 3). Is there any doc/explanations on Libratus in general ?

Thanks